# PLS-00215 String length constraints must be in range

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TABLE INTERVENCIONES(
"IDINTERVENCION" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
"NOMBREINTERVENCION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL,
"TIEMPOESPERADO" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
"NIF" CHAR(9 BYTE) REFERENCES VETERINARIOS NOT NULL,
"NUMEROCLIENTE" INTEGER REFERENCES CLIENTES NOT NULL,
"DIFICULTAD" CHAR (8 BYTE), CONSTRAINT "INTERVENCIONES_1" 
         CHECK (DIFICULTAD IN ('BAJA','MODERADA','ALTA','OTRO'))
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INTERVENCIONES BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON INTERVENCIONES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
LV_DIF VARCHAR2 := :NEW.DIFICULTAD;
LV_TIM NUMBER := :NEW.TIEMPOESPERADO;
BEGIN

    IF (LV_DIF LIKE 'BAJA' AND (LV_TIM>1)) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (num => 20005, msg => 'Siendo de riesgo bajo, debe durar menos de 1 hora');
   END IF;
END;
```

I want that if `DIFICULTAD` equals `BAJA`, `TIEMPOESPERADO` has to be more than 1. The error is:

> PLS-00215 String length constraints must be in range

Comment: the error message suggested you are using `Oracle` not `SQL Server`

Comment: YOu don't need to SHOUT at us in your title. Also the above is **not** T-SQL. There is no `VARCHAR2` datatype in SQL Server, nor is `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` a function.

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually need to define local variables.

```
IF (:NEW.DIFICULTAD LIKE 'BAJA' AND (:NEW.TIEMPOESPERADO > 1)) THEN
```

but if you want to define, you should do it right. varchar must be defined with an indication of the length: `VARCHAR2(<length>)`

pay attention to the length information. The can be the number of characters or bytes. that depends on the configuration of your database

e.g.

```
LV_DIF VARCHAR2(200) := :NEW.DIFICULTAD; -- 200
```

Comment: Just a note. The local variables are not needed just use "If :new.dificultad ... " and "LIKE" whit a wildcard is the same as equals.  Finally, you state "TIEMPOESPERADO has to be more than 1" however the if statements requires it to be 1 or less.

Comment: I’d prefer to anchor the type with `intervencion.dificultad%type` rather than hardcoding.